# Search query to database no action

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to ask a help regarding my problem in thesis PHP programming. My problem is below code. The case is if I have to search something regardless if the search query is in the database or not, there should always a message.

```
$sqlRet = "SELECT * FROM tblbookcopy WHERE rId = '$roomno' AND (ciDate = '$checkin' OR coDate = '$checkout')";

    if (mysqli_num_rows($conn,$sqlRet) != 0){
        $Message = urlencode("ERROR");
        // header("Location:index.php?Message=".$Message);
        header("Location: ../ac-hotel/reservationform.php?Message=".$Message);
        die;
    }
```

Willl you please enlighten me what I've missed. Thank you in advanced.

Regards,

Ray

Comment: You not add anything to the table. You have only a select?!

Comment: Select queries retrieve data; they don’t insert data. The code you posted doesn’t contain any code that attempts to add anything to a database.

Comment: Ill check on that. For a while sir.

Comment: Insert into tblbookcopy (column_name) values("column_values")

Comment: You've missed the PDO tutorial and the bits about preventing SQL injection.

Comment: I already refresh my question. Please do check.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an else part after the if statement something like:

```
else {
  $message = "Some Other Message";
  header("Location: ../ac-hotel/reservationform.php?Message=".$Message);
  die;
}
```